# How to fetch multiple live streams as an audience in agora using web sdk?

Tags: agora.io

How to fetch multiple live streams as an audience in agora using web sdk?
My use case is I am creating a web application where the screen is divided into 4 divs. Each div is fetching live stream as audience from 4 different channel similar to cctv monitors. Can I do this using agora?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using video or stream sdk?

**For the Audience**

You can create a client using the web-sdk, then create a handler to listen to when streams are added.
For example:

```
client.on('stream-added'
```

Where you then have to subscribe to each stream using

```
client.subscribe(stream
```

So if you are the audience, you will be listening for stream-added 4 times.
Then you can subscribe them and play them on different streams.

**For the Streamer**

You need to subscribe to the channel as usual, but set your role as *host*
You can then publish a stream, which will be notified to all your audience members.

Refer to the Quickstart guide for the full example:  https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/publish_web_live?platform=Web

Answer (score 0):

First create a client using web-Sdk then create handler to listen to them (client.on('stream-added')
then each created stream is to be subscribed(client.subscribe(stream)
And still if small doubts just check this site: https://medium.com/agora-io/video-calling-using-agoras-javascript-sdk-73ba0a315cbd